# Is there a way to automatically scale vertically azure cloud services (classic)?

Tags: azure, cloud

I have services that are still using the classic Azure cloud services.
Is there a way to vertical scale the cloud services automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to vertically scale a Classic Cloud Service automatically.

This is because the instance size is defined in `csdef` file that gets included in the package file (`cspkg`). Instance count is stored in configuration file (`cscfg`) and you can achieve horizontal scaling by changing the instance count there.

In order to change the instance size, you would need to update the csdef file, recompile your solution to create a package file and redeploy that package.